# @IBDesignable doesn't work in "old" project

Tags: xcode, ibdesignable

I have `UIView` subclass, for example, this:

```
@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var secondColor: UIColor = UIColor.green

    @IBInspectable var vertical: Bool = true

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        applyGradient()
    }

    func applyGradient() {
        let colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]

        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.colors = colors
        layer.frame = self.bounds
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        layer.endPoint = vertical ? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1) : CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)

        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        applyGradient()
    }
}
```

It successfully renders in Interface Builder for a new project, but it doesn't work for my "old" project. [image]

Does anyone know why it happens?

Comment: This may be a bug in Xcode. Many of my new projects did this and I essentially gave up on IBDesignables.

Comment: IBInspectable gets only 200mili second for a render on interface builder. Might be due to your size for the project it won;t properly render on interface builder.

Comment: It also works in the old project when I move the class to Cocoa Touch Framework target, but I I don't like this idea because I want to have access to the colors defined in my project.